# Developing a database server: How to send results to a client?

Tags: c, database, networking, database-server

I would like to create my own database server for educational purposes. My problem is, I cannot really find information about how these systems work. Now, I can create databases and tables and get data from it with basic select statements.

But, when a client connects to the database server, how should I send the result of a query back to the client? What format should be used to get good performance? What other things may need to be taken care of, given the specific scenario?

Comment: Even simple databases are extremely advanced systems. If you want stuff like query languages or relations or transactions then it becomes a magnitude (for each feature) harder.

Comment: "My specific question is when a client connects to the database server, how should I send the result of a query back to the client?". That would depend on how you intend connecting...

Comment: @moooeeeep: Basically, he want's to know "is there something like a general JDBC/ODBC standard?"

Comment: But a very valid question IMHO given the wider problem he is trying to solve...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many options, depending on your needs.

[JSON](http://www.json.org/) would allow almost any kind of client to use your database. It's also very easy to create but the format is somewhat verbose.

If you need a compact format, look at Google's [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) which has a text (= readable) and a binary form (= compact). Many languages support protobuf but not as many as JSON (yet).

I suggest not to try to come up with your own format; there are too many already and the task looks more simple than it is. If you make a mistake, it will be hard to fix, especially when others start to use your work.

Comment: Thank you, JSON will be a good start I think!